# Spring Batch Step/Job dependency

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch. I have a requirement to schedule multiple steps where one step is dependent on status of other step. Is there any way to make one step dependent on other step?

Answer (score 0):

yeah there is one solution that every job stores there status in mysql db so you can use that status to launch your another Step/Job accordingly.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to a wait job unit listener get updated from third party.